# cURL Request not sending paramaters

Tags: php, curl

I'll be honest I'm not 100% knowledgeable with cURL

However I am looking to use it to post an tweet with an image attached to it using Twitters API.

I've got my server script setup to output any $_GET variables. However the array is outputting as blank, So I'm assuming my cURL isnt posting properly.

My PHP code is as follows :

```
$url = 'http://www.website.com/tweet.php';

$myvars = 'access_token=' . $access_token . '&access_token_secret=' . $access_token_secret . '&message=' . $message . '&image=' . $image;

$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );

output($response);
```

The $response is returning an error from the Twtter API :

> [message] => Your credentials do not allow access to this resource

If I run the URL with all credentials in it in my browser, It works without issue.

Am I missing an additional curl_setopt ?

Cheers

Comment: try creating an array for your vars and pass the array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Comment: Hi @AdRock I've done that, Makes no difference.. Unfortunatley

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help but I had to use cURL for Google and YouTube

I've replaced some of your my vars with yours but it may be worth a try

```
<?php
// init the resource
$access_token = '';
$access_token_secret = '';
$message = '';
$image = '';

$url = 'http://www.website.com/tweet.php';

$clienttoken_post = array(
    "access_token" => $access_token,
    "access_token_secret" => $access_token_secret,
    "message" => $message,
    "image" => $image
);

$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $clienttoken_post);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

print_r( $json_response );
```

Failing that you could try the command line

```
curl --data "access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN&access_token_secret=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET&message=YOUR MESSAGE&image=YOUR_IMAGE" http://www.website.com/tweet.php
```